# How can DD4T request the broker with known component's URI and receive a component

Tags: dd4t

Could I request the broker server for a component sending the component's URI, using dd4t?

When I use ComponentFactory.TryGetComponent - it returns null for the object.

Using Tridion2011sp1 and DD4T 1.25

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
IComponent ComponentFactory.GetComponent(string componentUri, string templateUri = "");
```

or

```
bool ComponentFactory.TryGetComponent(string componentUri, out IComponent component, string templateUri = "");
```

are the correct methods.  If you are getting null, have you verified that the component presentation you're requesting is in the Broker DB, i.e. is published?

Comment: Nick is mentioning it already, but it's important to remember that you cannot request components. Under the hood it requests a ComponentPresentation and returns the component from that CP. This means that the ComponentPresentation should be published as a DCP to the broker.